# Partition debian while installation

Tags: debian, partition, debian-installer

I am trying to install Debian but i don't know how to partition it. I have an 1tb hard disk. I want to give 60gb for debian files,2gb for swap and want to use the others for media files. What is /,/home,/usr/local?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading some online resource about the installation, for example the [Debian Administrator's Handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.installation-steps.html) has a step-by-step installation guide, which includes some basic info you might need or want to know.

> What is /, /home, /usr/local?

`/`, `/home`, `/usr/local` are directories in the standard Linux filesystem structure.

By default, you will find a directory structure like this:

```
/
├── bin
├── boot
├── dev
├── etc
├── home
├── lib
├── media
├── mnt
├── opt
├── proc
├── root
├── run
├── sbin
├── srv
├── sys
├── tmp
├── usr
└── var
```

meaning that you have `/`, which is the root directory where all other directories (`bin`, `home`, `usr/local`, etc) are contained.

In short

- `/` is the root directory, where every file and directory starts.
- `/home` contains the home directories for all users to store their personal files, e.g. `/home/yourname` (notice how the path starts with `/`, which means the `home` directory is in `/`.
- `/usr` contains binaries, libraries, documentation, and source-code for programs

  - `/usr/local` contains users programs that you install from source.

For more detailed info on the directory structure, see for example [here](http://www.debianadmin.com/linux-directory-structure-overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is a highly taste thing.

In my opinion, better to run your whole system on a single big partition. Changing a running partition structure is not easy and risky, while you will surely find cases as your one of minor partition fills. And you can't put data in it, while you have space on the larger ones.

If you anyways want to use multiple partitions, in my opinion better to use lvm (logical volumes), particularly in many-disk setups, because they have the ability to make cross-disk partitions.

The old, partition table setup is a very rigid, very fragile one, its only right to live is if there is also a need for interaction with multiple OSes (dualbooted systems).